# How to update datetime column with value of timestamp column

Tags: mysql

I want to copy values of a column with dataType as TIMESTAMP into a column with datatype as DATETIME.

I have a table which has created_at (TIMESTAMP) and paid_at (DATETIME).
I want to copy values of created_at to paidAt.

I tried:

```
UPDATE TBL_NAME set paid_at=created_at;
```

But it is not giving expected results.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What resulst are you receiving instead?

Answer (score 0):

Instead please try:

```
UPDATE `TBL_NAME` set `paid_at` = STR_TO_DATE(`created_at`);
```

Comment: That's not what he asked for? He wants to copy from one column and not get a current timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `paid_at` = unix_timestamp(`created_at`);
```